# how to get option tag name from one jsp page to select tag of another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jasper-reports

Purchase.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="view.jsp">
<select name="category">
<option name=''> Make a selection </option>
<option name='company'>company</option>
<option name='institution'>institution</option>
<option name='hospital'>hospital</option>
<option name='Others'>Others</option>
</select>


<input type='submit' value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

view.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(nPage){
        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<% String Name=request.getParameter("category"); %>
<select  name="Name" onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option name="cat" value='PDF2.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option name="cat" value='XLS2.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX2.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp

<input type='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is i need to get "company" from purchase.jsp to `String Name` of view.jsp and get that "Name" into  `<select  name="Name" onchange="setAction(this.value)">` so that when i select "PDF.jsp" and click submit that pdf consists of only the data of "company" and nothing else.Here i am using jasper reports to get data into pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
<% String Name=request.getParameter("category"); %>
<select  name="<%=Name%>" onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option name="cat" value='PDF2.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option name="cat" value='XLS2.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX2.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Issam i tried your code but its not getting the data into pdf. I mean showing blank pdf file

Comment: I didnt get why your select should have name="company" for example?

Comment: Because when i am exporting into pdf file it should consists of only "company" data, but not like any other data for example "institutions","hospital".If i get entire "company","instittution" and "hospital" data then my pdf report will be a failure one.

Comment: <form>
<% String Name=request.getParameter("category"); %>
<select name="<%=Name%>" onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option value='PDF2.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option value='XLS2.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX2.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp

<input type='submit' value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: but no use i am getting blank pdf page

Comment: its lengthy code and stack overflow is saying like "characters are exceeded" so cannot be posted.Is there any other way?

Comment: How do you get the select value in PDF2.jsp or XLS2.jsp ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90794/discussion-between-guissouma-issam-and-chitti-oneterahertz).

Comment: I mean how do you get category value 'company' on PDF2.jsp or XLS2.jsp? you can use site like pastebin to post more data.